# File creates but cannot write in it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**My Program:** Check for Settings.txt file. If the file is not present, create the text and write into it automatically. If Settings.txt file is already present, ignore. Do not create or write in the existing file.

**My Problem:** When file is not present, Settings.txt file creates but it is empty. I want the program to write in it when it creates the file. Thanks for your help.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ver.2\Settings.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine("Manual Numbers=");
            tw.WriteLine("");
            tw.WriteLine("Installation Technical Manual: ");
            tw.WriteLine("Performance Manual: ");
            tw.WriteLine("Planned Maintenance Technical Manual: ");
            tw.WriteLine("Service Calibration Manual: ");
            tw.WriteLine("System Information Manual: ");
            tw.WriteLine("");
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I think happened.  when I copied and ran your code, an exception was thrown.  This is probably becaue you create your file **twice** and don't close it before you create it the second time.

For reference, `TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);` creates the file for you.  You don't need to call `File.Create`

and during subsequent runs, I don't think you're deleting the file, and since the file already exists, `if (!File.Exists(path))` will never be satisfied, and the entire `if` statement will be skipped

So there are multiple points here

- get rid of that `File.Create` call
- if you want the file to be over-written, you shouldn't check if it exists, you should just overwrite.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
    using(FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        tw.WriteLine("Manual Numbers=");
        tw.WriteLine("");
        tw.WriteLine("Installation Technical Manual: ");
        tw.WriteLine("Performance Manual: ");
        tw.WriteLine("Planned Maintenance Technical Manual: ");
        tw.WriteLine("Service Calibration Manual: ");
        tw.WriteLine("System Information Manual: ");
        tw.WriteLine("");
    }
```

The *using* ensures that the filestream is closed(disposed) even when an exception occurs within writing.

Comment: StreamWriter also needs to be disposed.

Comment: It's not nessesary because i own the stream and dispose it by myself. After that, i don't like the Dispose of a StreamWriter, because it's closing the filestream. (maybe unwanted)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that File.Create returns a FileStream so it leaves the file open.  You need to use that FileStream with your TextWriter.  You'll also want to wrp the FileStream in a using(...) statement or manually call Dispose() on the FileStream so you ensure the file is closed when you're done processing it.

Comment: And surrounding it in a using block, or manually disposing the streams would be a good thing too.

Answer (score 2):

though i am answering after quite some time but i guess i should answer

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("Manual Numbers=");
     sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     sb.Append("Installation Technical Manual: ");
     sb.Append("Performance Manual: ");
     sb.Append("Planned Maintenance Technical Manual: ");
     sb.Append("Service Calibration Manual: ");
     sb.Append("System Information Manual: ");
     sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     tw.Write(sb.ToString());
 }
```