# Can create csv but cannot write to it

Tags: wpf, vb.net, csv

My question is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475096/file-creates-but-cannot-write-in-it).  I can create the csv but cannot write to it once it is created.  But unlike that post, I am not creating the file twice.

My code:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\xxx\yyy\" & csvFileName

If File.Exists(path) = False Then
    ' Create a file to write to.
    Dim createText As String = String.Empty + Environment.NewLine
    File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
End If


Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(csvFileName, True)

'first, write all column names to csv.
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    sb.Append(col.ColumnName)
Next
sw.Write(sb.ToString)

'now, write rows to csv.
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    sb = New StringBuilder

    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName))
    Next

    sw.Write(sb.ToString)
Next

sw.Close()
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Which file are you referring to, "path" or "csvFileName" ? And what does "cannot write to it" mean? Are you getting an exception or what happens?

Comment: Oops, I see where I used csvFileName where I should have used path when I set the streamwriter.  I wasn't getting an exception, just no data in the csv. Thanks.

Comment: So this answers your question?

Comment: Yes.  Question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different file names here. The `StreamWriter` should write to `path` and not `csvFileName`:

```
Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problem in your code

1. you are not writing column delimiter
2. you are using file name instead of the full path
3. you are using `sw.Write()` method instead of `sw.WriteLine()` *(all text will be writed on one line)*

you can use the following code:

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\xxx\yyy\" & csvFileName

    If File.Exists(path) = False Then
    ' Create a file to write to.
        Dim createText As String = String.Empty + Environment.NewLine
        File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
    End If


    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)

        'first, write all column names to csv.
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            sb.Append(col.ColumnName & ",")
        Next

        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString)

        'now, write rows to csv.
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            sb = New StringBuilder

            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName).ToString  & ",")
            Next

            sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
        Next

        sw.Close()

    End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, Hadi.  Code has been modified and is functioning perfectly.

Comment: @EManning happy to help

Comment: @EManning It is a good idea to say thanks for a detailed and helpful answer and accepting and upvoting another one. Lol :)